# multivariate Gaussian distribution: Quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The multivariate Gaussian distribution is proportional to the quantity $\exp \{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu)^t (x-\mu)}{\Sigma^{-1}}\}$

Now, this can be written as: $\exp \{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^t \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\}$

Now, my very basic question is when we bring the $\Sigma$ matrix to the numerator, why does it go in the middle? I can see that the vector-matrix-vector multiplication makes sense but what is the rule behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it: $\exp \{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^t \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\}$ is proper whereas $\exp \{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu)^t (x-\mu)}{\Sigma}\}$ is sloppy and, at best, lazy.

If you want additional convincing, consider the dimensions of the involved quantities.

Comment: The sloppy way is also difficult for me to understand. I mean the top quantity is a scalar and the bottom is a matrix. What does a $\frac{scalar}{matrix}$ quantity actually mean? 

So the multivariate Gaussian is actually defined this way?

Comment: Like you have said, scalar/matrix doesn't mean much. So you should always write it as $\exp \{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^t \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\}$ and forget about the other notation.